# SELECT on JSON operations of Postgres array column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of type `jsonb[]` (a Postgres array of `jsonb` objects) and I'd like to perform a SELECT on rows where a criteria is met on at least one of the objects. Something like:

```sql
-- Schema would be something like
mytable (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  col2 jsonb[] NOT NULL
);

-- Query I'd like to run
SELECT
  id,
  x->>'field1' AS field1
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  x->>'field2' = 'user' -- for any x in the array stored in col2
```

I've looked around at `ANY` and `UNNEST` but it's not totally clear how to achieve this, since you can't run `unnest` in a `WHERE` clause. I also don't know how I'd specify that I want the `field1` from the matching object.

Do I need a `WITH` table with the values expanded to join against? And how would I achieve that and keep the `id` from the other column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and then you can access each json value

```
SELECT t.id,
       c.x ->> 'field1' AS field1
FROM mytable t
  cross join unnest(col2) as c(x)
WHERE c.x ->> 'field2' = 'user'
```

This will return one row for each json value in the array.